# Android LiveWallpaper xOffset confusing?

Tags: android

In android, xOffset values confusing me, if you have 5 screen it goes like, 0.0 - 0.25 - 0.5 - 0.75 - 1, so for example, if xOffset is 1 you are on the 5th screen.

I have a image with width 1000. I want to have scroll effect for the image, I update image X position with xOffset;

```
   public void update() {   
        float newImageX =  - (X_OFFSET * image.getWidth());
        image.setX(newWorldX);
   }
```

But it moves too much. For example, user has 5 screens, int 5th screen xOffset is 1, due to my algorithm, all imgae moves out of screen.

I confused about, Obviously I need more useful data/values to calculate the movement effect. Any ideas ?